# No type named 'atomic' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

Why doesn't

```
std::atomic<int> index;
```

Work?

Currently using LLVM 3.1 with these params

```
C Language Dialect GNU [-std=gnu99]
C++ Language Dialect [-std=c++11]
C++ Standard Library libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)
```

Comment: Have you `#include`d the `<atomic>` header?

Comment: @AndyProwl
#error <atomic> is not implemented

I guess that's that

Comment: Sounds likely. Btw, it is a good habit to provide also the error message you get (if you received any). "Doesn't work" could mean anything.

Comment: @AndyProwl

Oh, the only error message I got was the title of the question

Comment: Oh, OK, I hadn't realized that was the message you got.

Comment: Try downloading the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: According to the [status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), atomics were implemented in Clang 3.2.

Answer (score 15):

There are several things that need to be true for your code to work:

1. You need to `#include <atomic>`
2. You need to compile the code as C++11 or C++14 (`-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` (or `c++0x` for older compilers))
3. Your compiler and standard library needs to support enough of C++11 to provide `atomic` (http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

Comment: adding -std=c++11 to my cmake_cxx_flags worked. thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to disable some GNU extensions (e.g. so `asm` works as well as `__asm__`), you can use `-std=gnu++20` instead of `c++20`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `-std=c++11` to CXXFLAGS in my Makefile -> that works for me!